# I2c Bus with Raspberry Pi (Python) programming question

Tags: python, i2c

basically i need to switch my output modules on and off with python for my project and put it in a loop.

```
import smbus
import time

b = smbus.SMBus(1)

for x in range(0, 3):
b.write_byte_data(0x20, 0x14, 0xDB)
b.write_byte_data(0x24, 0x14, 0xD6)
time.sleep(1)
b.write_byte_data(0x20, 0x14, 0x04)
b.write_byte_data(0x20, 0x14, 0xFD)
```

my problem is, the 7th line of code switches 2 outputs on, and in the 10th and 11th line i want one of them to turn off, but the other one to still be turned on. I'm rather new to programming, and don't have much knowledge about what I'm doing.
First I tried turning them on one by one:

```
b.write_byte_data(0x20, 0x14, 0xFB)
b.write_byte_data(0x20, 0x14, 0xDF)
```

but that only switched the first one on for a split second and then off again (the last one stayed on). That's why I added them together in Hex. Now they're both turning off when I'm doing:

```
 b.write_byte_data(0x20, 0x14, 0x04)
```

Or is there a better way to switch on multiple outputs and then switch off a single output at a time? I hope it's understandable, my English isn't very good I'm sorry.

Comment: You have a `sleep()` after the first 2 writes, but not after the second 2. That means the first 2 will execute immediately after the second 2. Not sure if that's what you want, but I'm guessing a `time.sleep(1)` at the end might help.

Comment: I tried it, but didn't do anything.
    b.write_byte_data(0x20, 0x14, 0xDB) 
turns on 2 LEDs and with 
    b.write_byte_data(0x20, 0x14, 0x04)
i want to turn off 1 of those LEDs. The other one must stay on.